# I want to add a animated button from left side of a screen on slide that icon drawer should open in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to add a animated button from left side of a screen on slide that icon drawer should open in flutter.

I have a webview app, I want to add a button in middle of screen in left side.

how can I add a button please help me with that.

I think floatingaction button won't work this way.

[image: see the design]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Positioned` widget to place that button/arrow at that specific part of screen

```
Positioned(
  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2
  left: 0
  child: //arrow widget here
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much  for your answer. 

I am using positioned like this it is not working.

  SafeArea(
          child: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: _exitApp,
            child: Scaffold(
             
              body: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
                      left: 0,
                      child: Lottie.asset("assets/images/arrow.json")
                  ),

InAppwebview();

Comment: any errors? you you add a picture too?